# startx failing from debian console in virtualbox VM: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, x11, console

I'm running debian testing within a VirtualBox VM (Windows 10 host, VBox 5.2.20), and booting to the console.  I used to be able to run startx just fine once logged in, but for the past while it hasn't worked, and I'd like to fix it.

I've been getting by for a while by going into the advanced boot, choosing failsafe, pressing CTRL-D when prompted for maintenance mode password, then logging in normally and running startx, which works.

One notable difference in the logs between normal boot and failsafe boot is that there's an error regarding `/dev/dri/card0` not existing when invoking startx after a normal boot, but `/dev/dri/card0` is found and used in the startx from the failsafe boot.

Here's the full contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when I attempt to run startx after logging into the console.

```
[  1389.124] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1389.125] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  1389.125] Current Operating System: Linux vm-stretch-amd64 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-10-07) x86_64
[  1389.125] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=3e8c1e3c-233e-4ece-975f-29e2e0d54691 ro nomodeset
[  1389.125] Build Date: 26 September 2018  10:20:47AM
[  1389.125] xorg-server 2:1.20.1-4 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  1389.125] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  1389.125]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1389.125] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1389.126] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Oct 27 21:04:35 2018
[  1389.126] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1389.126] (==) Using system config directory 
"/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1389.126] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1389.126] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1389.126] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1389.126] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1389.127] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1389.127] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1389.127] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1389.127] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1389.127] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1389.127] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[  1389.127] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1389.127] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1389.127] (II) Loader magic: 0x558f7b1d5e20
[  1389.127] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1389.127]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1389.127]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[  1389.127]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1389.127]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1389.127] (++) using VT number 1

[  1389.129] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_37
[  1389.131] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 80ee:beef:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/134217728, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1389.131] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1389.131] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1389.132] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.132]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1389.132]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1389.132] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1389.132] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1389.132] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1389.132] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  1389.132] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1389.132] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
[  1389.132] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vboxvideo
[  1389.132] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1389.132] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1389.133] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1389.133] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.133]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.20.1
[  1389.133]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1389.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1389.133] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1389.133] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1389.133] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.133]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[  1389.133]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1389.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1389.133] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1389.133] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1389.133] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.133]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[  1389.133]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1389.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1389.133] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1389.133] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1389.133] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1389.133] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1389.133] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  1389.133] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1389.133] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1389.133] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1389.133] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1389.133] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.133]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  1389.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1389.133] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[  1389.133] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1389.133] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1389.133] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1389.133] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1389.133] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1389.133]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  1389.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[  1389.133] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[  1389.133] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  1389.133] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  1389.133] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  1389.133] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1389.133] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1389.133] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1389.133] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[  1389.133] (EE) 
[  1389.133] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1389.133] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1389.133] (EE) 
[  1389.141] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

For comparison purposes, here's the first part of the contents of `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`, which appears to contain the log for the successful startx from failsafe mode.  I truncated it because StackExchange has a maximum character limit on posts.

```
[   363.740] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   363.744] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   363.747] Current Operating System: Linux vm-stretch-amd64 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-10-07) x86_64
[   363.747] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=3e8c1e3c-233e-4ece-975f-29e2e0d54691 ro single
[   363.751] Build Date: 26 September 2018  10:20:47AM
[   363.752] xorg-server 2:1.20.1-4 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   363.753] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   363.756]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   363.756] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   363.762] (==) Log file: "/home/dave/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", 
Time: Sat Oct 27 21:14:52 2018
[   363.764] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   363.765] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   363.765] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   363.765] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   363.765] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   363.765] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   363.766] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[   363.766] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   363.766] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   363.766] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   363.766] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   363.766] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
        built-ins
[   363.766] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   363.766] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   363.766] (II) Loader magic: 0x555c7febbe20
[   363.766] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   363.766]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   363.766]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   363.766]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   363.766]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   363.767] (++) using VT number 1

[   363.769] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   363.769] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   363.770] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[   363.771] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 80ee:beef:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/134217728, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   363.771] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   363.771] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   363.773] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.773]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   363.773]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   363.773] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 0
[   363.773] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   363.773] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   363.773] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   363.773] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   363.773] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
[   363.773] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vboxvideo
[   363.773] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[   363.773] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   363.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   363.773] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.773]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.20.1
[   363.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   363.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   363.773] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   363.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   363.773] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.773]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[   363.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   363.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   363.773] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   363.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   363.773] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.773]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[   363.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   363.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   363.773] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   363.773] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   363.773] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   363.773] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   363.773] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[   363.773] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   363.773] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   363.773] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   363.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   363.774] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.774]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   363.774]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   363.774] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   363.774] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   363.774] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   363.774] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[   363.774] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   363.774] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   363.774] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   363.774] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   363.777] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   363.778]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.1
[   363.778]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   363.834] (EE) modeset(0): eglGetDisplay() failed
[   363.835] (EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): ShadowFB: preferred NO, enabled NO
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: VBX  Model: 0  Serial#: 70780800
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Year: 1990  Week: 1
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Indeterminate output size
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Default color space is primary color space
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.312 whiteY: 0.329
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): clock: 125.5 MHz   Image Size:  0 x 0 mm
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1922  h_sync_end 1924 h_blank_end 1926 h_border: 0
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1080  v_sync_end 1114 v_blanking: 1086 v_border: 0
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Ranges: V min: 0 V max: 200 Hz, H min: 0 H max: 200 kHz, PixClock max 1005 MHz
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Monitor name: VBOX monitor
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff005858000080073804
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   0100010380000078eeee91a3544c9926
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   0f505400000001010101010101010101
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   01010101010105318006703806400202
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   0202000000000000000000fd0000c800
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   c864000a202020202020000000fc0056
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   424f58206d6f6e69746f720a00000010
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0):   000a20202020202020202020202000f0
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  173.11  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync (67.2 kHz P)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1600"x60.0  348.50  2560 2752 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync (99.5 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1600"x60.0  268.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1600 1603 1609 1646 +hsync -vsync (98.7 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1440"x60.0  234.00  1920 2048 2256 2600  1440 1441 1444 1500 -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1856x1392"x60.0  218.25  1856 1952 2176 2528  1392 1393 1396 1439 -hsync +vsync (86.3 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1792x1344"x60.0  204.75  1792 1920 2120 2448  1344 1345 1348 1394 -hsync +vsync (83.6 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2048x1152"x60.0  162.00  2048 2074 2154 2250  1152 1153 1156 1200 +hsync +vsync (72.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x59.9  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync (74.6 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x60.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 -hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x59.9  101.00  1400 1448 1480 1560  1050 1053 1057 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  108.00  1600 1624 1704 1800  900 901 904 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   363.835] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1366x768"x59.8   85.50  1366 1436 1579 1792  768 771 774 798 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
(a bunch more shows up, but the site limits posts to 30K characters)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are doing VGA passthrough, which I doubt it is the case as few people are doing it, `nomodeset` should not be present on your kernel configuration/in a virtual environment.

Also, you must be paying a premium in performance using the framebuffer under vbox for graphical mode.

I would advise also installing and using the VBox guest additions. Besides better support for video modes, you will have better performance.

[VBox user manual - Chapter 4. Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

> Better video support While the virtual graphics card which VirtualBox
>   emulates for any guest operating system provides all the basic
>   features, the custom video drivers that are installed with the Guest
>   Additions provide you with extra high and non-standard video modes as
>   well as accelerated video performance.
>
> In addition, with Windows, Linux and Solaris guests, you can resize
>   the virtual machine's window if the Guest Additions are installed. The
>   video resolution in the guest will be automatically adjusted (as if
>   you had manually entered an arbitrary resolution in the guest's
>   display settings). Please see Section 1.9.5, “Resizing the machine's
>   window” also.
>
> Finally, if the Guest Additions are installed, 3D graphics and 2D
>   video for guest applications can be accelerated; see Section 4.5,
>   “Hardware-accelerated graphics”.
>
> Seamless windows With this feature, the individual windows that are
>   displayed on the desktop of the virtual machine can be mapped on the
>   host's desktop, as if the underlying application was actually running
>   on the host. See Section 4.6, “Seamless windows” for details.

Comment: So, that's interesting.  Removing "nomodeset" from the boot line does resolve the inability for X to start, but only at the cost of making the console mode unusably small (the console also appears very small in failsafe mode).  Previously, the console was occupying the entire 1920x1080 screen (I believe this is why I had nomodeset enabled to begin with).  Without nomodeset, it's a tiny 640x480 centred on-screen.  Building guest additions via DKMS started failing with 4.19 kernel.  I reverted to 4.18; virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-x11 are installed. (Used to use .run from Oracle.)

Comment: nomodeset and framebuffer might be useful to deal with non supported hw, but a big waste of CPU in a VM

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it did resolve the question asked, even though it's unusable for me on account of the console becoming horribly small.

Comment: Which console, text or xterm or...?

Comment: The ttys accessible via function keys.   I have graphical boot disabled, and only run startx when I actually want a graphical windowing system.  Much of the time I just want to do software development from the text console, which works well if I can use the full 1920x1080 resolution, but rather poorly when I get only a small text screen in the middle surrounded by a lot of black.